# Sorting an array arbitrarily in cakephp

Tags: arrays, sorting, cakephp

I have an array which is dynamic, and key and values are displaying in order if they are set.  I want to display keys of this array in my own order, What kind of condition must I write in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Core Utility Libraries, namely the sort() method of the Set class. Check for more info [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1490/sort).

Comment: `$myArray = Set::sort($myArray, '{n}.Post.name', 'asc');`. More examples in the link above. You simply pass your array, a path to the array key to be sorted on (see [path syntax](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1488/Set-compatible-Path-syntax)), and a direction to sort in.